# IAME KA100 go-kart engine will not 'cough': Can you recommend what to check next?

Tags: engine

I recently purchased an IAME KA100 engine and am trying to get it to 'cough' (let alone start), and would like suggestions for what to check next. Here is what I've checked so far:

- Compression is 125 PSI
- I pulled the spark plug and held it against the block, and turned it over, and i can see it sparking regularly
- I attached the exhaust
- I opened the throttle fully and sprayed WD-40 in, then closed the throttle to say 1/4 open, and hit the starter. I couldn't find any aerostart but i figure for a quick test, WD-40 should work?

Unfortunately it won't even cough, so i'm not sure if it's likely to need a full rebuild or maybe i'm missing something.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WD40 will help make the engine not start.

Try a teaspoonful of petrol into the air intake instead. Fresh of course, but you will need to take the plug out and dry it after the WD40.